# nHibernate Collection Count

Tags: nhibernate, collections, lazy-loading

I have the following model which I have created and mapped with nHibernate.
Using lazy loading so I don't need to get the Vehicles for the Dealer at the start.

```
Public class Dealer
{
public virtual string Name { get;set;}
public virtual IList<Vehicles> Vehicles { get;set;}
}
```

Now let's assume the Dealer has thousands of vehicles.

If I do `Dealer.Vehicles.Count` then NH will select and pull all the data.

What is the best way to simply get a count?  Is there any way in which I can get a count with out declaring A new property dealerCount within the Dealer Class?

Also there is a feature in Hibernate which I believe will be implemented in a newer version of NH called Extra Lazy Loading. Would this solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

extra lazy loading would issue sql instead of populating the collection for certain operations such as `Count` or `Contains`. In fluent mappings its used as:

```
HasMany(x => x.CollectionProperty).ExtraLazyLoad();
```

or HBM

```
<one-to-many lazy="extra" ...
```

It's only usefull if you have large collections and need the special behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use count projection (Projections.RowCount)